# Best practice when interacting with Room and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences, android-room

I'm using a `Room` table that takes an `entity` that has a "Favorited" `boolean` field, which is by default `False`, but can be made `True` through `user input`. The `database` needs to be wiped periodically and repopulated by a `network call`. Doing so naturally reverts all "Favorited" fields to `False`.

Using `SharedPreferences`, I can keep a second, persistent list of Favorited `entities`, but what's the cleanest way to repopulate `Room` and hold on to the favorites?

Using `RxKotlin` here for clarity, if not accuracy,
should it be something like

```
saveEntities()
 .flatMapIterable { it }
            .map{ 
                 if (sharedPrefs.contains(it.id)) 
                       it.apply{favorite} 
                 else it }
            .toList()
            .subscribe()
```

Or should I `serialize` a list of favorites, save that to `SharedPreferences`, and then

```
val favoritesList = PrefSerializer().getFavorites
saveEntities()
 .map{ it.forEach{ 
            if (favoritesList.contains(it)) 
                it.apply{favorite} 
            else it}
  }
 .subscribe()
```

Or does it even make sense to store Favorite information in `Room`?
Referencing `SharedPreferences` every time an entity is called feels like bad practice.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a separate table for favorites and *not* wipe that when you wipe the main table?

Comment: Could, I reckon. Seems like over coding for what would be likely be a small list . In any case, I would still need to cross reference the data, and doing that in the most untaxing way is what I'm looking for. The data itself is volatile, so cloning entities and saving them to a different table seems imprudent.

Comment: There's a hundred ways to solve it, I'm asking my betters if there's a best practice here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using 2 tables in Room because that way you can use a database view to combine them. Room can monitor the tables and notify the UI via LiveData. You can technically monitor SharedPreferences, but I believe it is in fact more tedious.

For example, this is a table where data is periodically overwritten by sync.

```
@Entity
data class Cheese(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val name: String
)
```

And you have a separate table to hold the "favorite" status.

```
@Entity
data class CheeseFavorite(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    val favorite: Boolean
)
```

Then you can create a database view like this to combine 2 tables.

```
@DatabaseView(
    """
    SELECT c.id, c.name, f.favorite
    FROM Cheese AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CheeseFavorite AS f
    ON c.id = f.id
    """
)
data class CheeseDetail(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val favorite: Boolean?
)
```

The view can be queried just like a table. You can of course use LiveData or Rx data types as the return type.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM CheeseDetail")
fun all(): List<CheeseDetail>
```